# ElasticSearch - Analyser for searching Products in URLS

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-analyzers

I am new in ES.

I have 3000 Keywords and need to match them to millions of URLs which have url encoded chars like "+".

Like

```
www.nicecars.com/BrownCars_Nice_Sedan_with-Wheels_4+
www.nicecars.com/BrownCars_Nice_Sedan_with-Wheels_4
```

Where `BrownCars` is the brand.

So far the best working analyzer is `pattern` but its dropping the `+` which is important.

So how can I un-filter characters like `+` ?

Or is there a better analyzer for this task?

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your pattern analyzer and in Char filter don't filter the `+`.

[Analysis](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analyzer-anatomy.html) process consists of below three steps:

1. Char filter (here you can add/remove certain characters from the text)
2. Tokenizer (break the text into tokens)
3. Token filter (converts token into small case etc)

It would be useful to provide your pattern analyzer definition, so we can test from our side and modify it according to your need.